# How can I make pyautogui tell me the coordinates of the locateOnScreen function

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

My goal for this right now is to be able to receive the coordinates from the `pyautogui` function `locateOnScreen` and use the returned coordinates to click an object on the screen. I know how to use coordinates to click on screen but I cannot find the coordinates from the `locateOnScreen` function

### Code

This is what I have so far which finds an object on the screen and determines if the object is visible. I just need to grab the coordinates of the object.

```py
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random

while True:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('x1.png', confidence=0.9) is not None:
        print("I can see it")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("I can not see the X")
        time.sleep(2)
```

### x1.png

[image: x1.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html?highlight=locate#the-locate-functions): The return value of the `locateOnScreen` function holds the coordinates.

```py
x1_coordinates = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('x1.png', confidence=0.9)
print(x1_coordinates)  # This will print out where it is

if x1_coordinates:
    print(f"I can see it at {x1_coordinates}")
else:
    print("I cannot see it.")
```

UPDATE: In chat, we've also discussed clicking on that object. For that, you can use `locateCenterOnSCreen` or `pyautogui.click(x.left + 3, x.top - 3)` (which is a bit of a hack and I wouldn't recommend using it).

Comment: so I did this but the click is off im not sure why

`from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random

while True:
    x1_coordinates = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('x1.png', confidence=0.9)
    print(x1_coordinates)  # This will print out where it is
    if x1_coordinates:
        print(f"I can see it at {x1_coordinates}")
        pyautogui.click(x1_coordinates)
    else:
        print("I cannot see it.")`

Comment: What do you mean by "the click is off"? Can you be more exact and maybe give some more details on what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: like it doesn't click in the right spot and sorry it doesn't seem to be formatting the code correctly

Comment: All good. Try to either add/subtract 2-3 pixels to the X and Y coordinates to hit the correct spot, or maybe use locateCenterOnScreen, instead.

Comment: Sure! If it works for you, be sure to accept this answer and tell me what worked - I'll edit my answer accordingly for future Googlers :)

Comment: how do I do that the formatting is weird becuase it prints this "Box(left=2422, top=157, width=34, height=34)" so im not sure how I could do that

could I just do left =-1 or something like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229108/discussion-between-caminero-and-shay-nehmad).

Answer (score 1):

Use [locateCenterOnScreen](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) to get `x` and `y` coodinates:

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    try:
        x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('x1.png')
        print(f'I can see it at: {x}x{y}')
    except TypeError:
        print('I can not see it')
```

Output:

```
I can not see it
I can see it at: 960x571
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be persizes how can I subtract pixels from the coordinate

Comment: Use `pyautogui.click(x, y)` to click the button

Comment: but its not persize so it doesn't click in the right spot how do I fix this

Comment: It does click on button. What do you want to click?

Comment: I want it to click on an x button on my screen but its completely off im about to create another question with a better explanation

Comment: here is the new discussion for this issue please help with what you can

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66338786/locateonscreen-coordinates-are-off